# correct syntax for handling arrays internet explorer 9

Tags: javascript

I know that it does not make sense to be thinking about an obsolete browser but for the development that I am doing, I must provide support for it.
My code works correctly in google chrome, but when I try it in internet explorer 9 I get this error:

```
SCRIPT1028: An identifier, string or number was expected
```

What other syntax can I use to avoid it? thank you very much

```
nombresColumnas=["data0","data1","data2","data3"];

{
 [nombresColumnas[0]]: '#33E789',   //error here..!
 [nombresColumnas[1]]: '#00CCFF',
 [nombresColumnas[2]]: '#FFC33E',
 [nombresColumnas[3]]: '#384858'
}
```

output of last code:

```
{ "data0" : '#33E789'},
{ "data1": '#00CCFF'},
{ "data2": '#FFC33E'},
{ "data3": '#384858'}
```

Comment: IE does not support this ES6 syntax.  You need to transpile.

Comment: You will have to write like `obj[nombresColumnas[0]]='#33E789'` or loop the nombresColumnas

Comment: what is @SLaks ??

Comment: you are using EcmaScript 6 syntax, which is fairly recent. Internet Explorer 9 - which is not updated anymore, does not understand. EcmaScript is actually the language standard behind JavaScript. Transpile means transform from a language to another.

Comment: @Joschi what is obj??